# Writing values of rdd at path specified in key in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create parquet files of values stored in values at at path specified in key.

```
#key is path where the value is to written
rdd = sc.parallelize([('/user/dir_a','tableA'),('/user/dir_b','tableB'),('/user/dir_c','tableC')])
```

So at path /user/dir_a , A is written

What I did:

```
def writeToHdfs(x):
  path = x[0]
  outputpath = OUT_DIR + path
  log.info('Creating dataframe')
  s = SparkSession(sc)
  df = s.createDataFrame(x[1], schema))
  df.write.parquet(outputpath )

rdd.foreach(writeToHdfs)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe , there is no out of the box solution for the scenario. Code is in Scala but logic is same for python.

```
 val baseRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("/user/dir_a", "tableA"), ("/user/dir_b", "tableB"), ("/user/dir_c", "tableC"))).cache()

    val groupedRDD = baseRDD.groupByKey()

    //Bring the keys to driver.Its little expensive operation
   // but we need keys(paths) after all.
    val keys = groupedRDD.keys.collect()

    //Create RDDs specific to ur paths
    val rddList = keys.map { key =>

      val rdd = baseRDD.filter(f => f._1.==(key))

      (key, rdd)
    }

    //Now you have list of RDDs specific to paths. iterate each RDD and save them to file  
    rddList.foreach(f => {

      val path = f._1
      f._2.values.saveAsTextFile(path)
    })
```

Note: Cache your RDD wherever you feel that it needs to gain performance. replace `saveAsTextFile(...)` with your respective method.

Comment: I got the following error while creating rddList. Looks like spark doesn't like the filter funtion inside map.Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Comment: keys.map{} is not spark map but its Scala collection map. and It worked for me without any issue before I post the answer...

Comment: Ohh. It works for text file but since I am using dataframe, createDataframe raises exception. Original rdd.take(1) gives [(path,[[row1],[row2])] wile now in rddList each rdd.take(1) gives [(path,[[[row],[row2]]] and hence not able to create dataframe. I want that original one value of original rdd to be present as multiple values in the child rdd that is, the new rdd in rddList should have 4 key,value pairs given that there are four rows in table. Sorry I didn't mention it earlier. Can you please help?

Comment: Okay.. Hope you might have got some idea from it.

Comment: NP. Happy to help always

Comment: Thank you very much. Applying flatMap on top of this worked. Thanks